# How to format HTTParty POST request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, post, httparty

I've been playing around with API calls for a project I'm working on and I'm getting a problem when I try to pass some JSON to a POST request. The call works in Postman, but I just can't figure out how to format it in Ruby. Here's my code:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'
require 'pp'
#use the HTTParty gem
include HTTParty
#base_uri 'https://app.api.com'
#set some basic things to make the call,
@apiUrl = "https://app.api.com/"
@apiUrlEnd = 'apikey=dontStealMePls'
@apiAll = "#{@apiUrl}#{@apiUrlEnd}"
@apiTest = "https://example.com"

def cc_query
  HTTParty.post(@apiAll.to_s, :body => {
    "header": {"ver": 1,"src_sys_type": 2,"src_sys_name": "Test","api_version": "V999"},
    "command1": {"cmd": "cc_query","ref": "test123","uid": "abc01",  "dsn": "abcdb612","acct_id": 7777}
    })
end

def api_test
  HTTParty.post(@apiTest.to_s)
end

#pp api_test()
pp cc_query()
```

This code gives me this error:

```
{"fault"=>
  {"faultstring"=>"Failed to execute the ExtractVariables: Extract-Variables",
   "detail"=>{"errorcode"=>"steps.extractvariables.ExecutionFailed"}}}
```

I know that error because I would get it if I tried to make a call without any JSON in the body of the call (through Postman). So from that I assume that my code above is not passing any JSON when making an API call. Am I formatting my JSON incorrectly? Am I even formatting the .post call correctly? Any help is appreciated! :)

the api_test() method just makes a POSt call to example.com and it works (saving my sanity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use HTTParty as a mixin instead in a class instead:

```
require 'httparty'

class MyApiClient
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://app.api.com'
  format :json
  attr_accessor :api_key

  def initalize(api_key:, **options)
    @api_key = api_key
    @options = options
  end

  def cc_query
    self.class.post('/', 
      body: {
        header: {
          ver: 1,
          src_sys_type: 2,
          src_sys_name: 'Test',
          api_version: 'V999'
        },
        command1: {
          cmd: 'cc_query',
          ref: 'test123',
          uid: 'abc01',
          dsn: 'abcdb612',
          acct_id: 7777
        }
      }, 
      query: {
        api_key: api_key
      }
    ) 
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
MyApiClient.new(api_key: 'xxxxxxxx').cc_query
```

When you use `format :json` HTTParty will automatically set the content type and handle JSON encoding and decoding. I'm guessing thats where you failed.

Comment: This definitely pointed me in the right direction, now that I'm getting an Invalid API Key error compared to the one from above. I'm just a bit confused, when I put in the API key when using the example usage, I'm getting an incorrect API key error (I'm pasting the key as I have it). Any help?

Comment: There isn't really that much I can do without knowing the API.